# Question on transforming a sum to an integral using the Euler–Maclaurin formula.

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, power-series, euler-maclaurin

I have a question regarding transforming a summation to an integral using the Euler–Maclaurin formula. Imagine I have this sum
$$\sum_{i=0}^{m} f(i)  \qquad \text{with} \qquad f(i)= \exp [(\frac{a}{b+c+i})^2]  $$
where the upper limit $m$ is a finite non-negative integer, and $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$. My major is not Math; searching on the internet, I see that I can use the  Euler–Maclaurin formula as follows (the source of the picture is [WIKIPEDIA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) )
[image]
where it is written that `for p a positive integer and a function f(x) that is p times continuously differentiable on the interval [m,n]`

**My questions:**

1. Can I use this formula for my function $f(i)$? More precisely, I mean does this part `a function f(x) that is p times continuously differentiable on the interval [m,n]` apply to my case too?
2. Then, will the new summation (the 3rd term in the formula) be convergent?
3. Is the error term $R_p$ negligible compared to the other terms?
4. Is there any simpler formula that I can use to transform my summation to an integral?

I appreciate any help and comments.